# Missing composer/zend command: development-enable

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework, composer-php

When I install Zend via `composer create-project -n -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application` as specified by Zend's main tutorial, I get a skeleton application that seems to work nicely.

However, when I follow this tutorial's advice to use `composer development-enable`, I get the following message:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
Command "development-enable" is not defined.
```

**Is anyone able to duplicate/fix this problem?**

I would normally assume it's an issue with the bash $PATH value, but the `composer` command by itself runs just fine, so I'm thinking it may be some other problem specific to this subcommand -- a missing dependency somewhere, for example.

Here is the relevant piece of the tutorial I am trying to follow:

https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/skeleton-application/

(In case it helps for purposes of duplication: The CLI PHP version on my development server is 5.4.43. For reasons I won't bore you with, I can't update this CLI PHP to a newer version; the major release that Apache is using on my machine is 5.6.)

---

EDIT 1: Rerunning my installation using `composer create-project -s dev zendframework/skeleton-application` (as specified in the linked tutorial) still results in the same problem.

---

EDIT 2: Here is my shell input/output.

```
patrick [~/www/berlin-data]# composer create-project -n -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application
Installing zendframework/skeleton-application (2.3.3)
  - Installing zendframework/skeleton-application (2.3.3)
    Loading from cache

Created project in /home1/patrick/public_html/berlin-data/skeleton-application
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing zendframework/zendxml (1.0.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.3.3)
    Loading from cache

zendframework/zendframework suggests installing doctrine/annotations (Doctrine Annotations >=1.0 for annotation features)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing ircmaxell/random-lib (Fallback random byte generator for Zend\Math\Rand if OpenSSL/Mcrypt extensions are unavailable)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing ocramius/proxy-manager (ProxyManager 0.5.* to handle lazy initialization of services)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zendpdf (ZendPdf for creating PDF representations of barcodes)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha (ZendService\ReCaptcha for rendering ReCaptchas in Zend\Captcha and/or Zend\Form)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files


patrick [~/www/berlin-data]# cd skeleton-application/

patrick [~/www/berlin-data/skeleton-application]# composer development-enable

  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "development-enable" is not defined.
```

Comment: Try `composer "development-enable"` with quotes around development-enable

Comment: Good suggestion, but this too results in the same error.

Comment: What CLI are you using? Windows Powershell? basic cmd.exe? Or are you on some other system?

Comment: Good question, Chausser. I am using a bash shell. (I have now edited the question to include this information.)

Comment: in your composer.json in the `scripts` section is `development-enabled` defined? If so are you running the composer command from the root directory of the project where the composer.json lives?

Comment: The composer.json file contains only this line: `"require":{"zendframework/zendframework": "^2.4"} ` 
... so I think we found at least a partial culprit, though we don't know *why* the composer.json file never populated. Interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the command

```
composer create-project -n -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application
```

This will create a directory in your current dir called `skeleton-application` inside of this directory is where you need to run the command:

```
composer development-enable
```

If this still doesnt work then something went wrong with install process.

The first command should give out put something like:

```
$ composer create-project -n -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application
Installing zendframework/skeleton-application (dev-master 941da45b407e4f09e264f0                                             00fb537928badb96ed)
  - Installing zendframework/skeleton-application (dev-master master)
    Cloning master from cache

Created project in C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\skeleton-application
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
  - Installing zendframework/zend-component-installer (0.3.0)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (3.0.1)
    Downloading: 100%
...
```

Notice this line `Created project in C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\skeleton-application`

Thats the directory you need to be in to run the command:

```
cd C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\skeleton-application
composer development-enable
```

If that still didnt work, try specifying the version for downloading:

```
composer create-project -n "zendframework/skeleton-application":"dev-master"
```

**PS**

As of writing this the skeleton application requires PHP `"^5.6 || ^7.0"`. So if you are running a lower version composer wont install that copy. And the tutorials based on it may not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I have added some additional information to the question, showing specifics of how this fails.

Comment: Looks like you are getting an old version of the skeleton application that wasnt setup with the composer command you are trying to run. Try clearing your composer cache and installing the skeleton application again. `composer clear-cache`

Comment: No such luck. Running my install line after a `composer self-update` followed by `composer clear-cache` still results in version 2.33 being downloaded. I even tried removing the `-n` and `-sdev` arguments, but no luck -- my install line still ends up installing version 2.33 of Zend. Composer is on version 1.2.1 (stable channel).

Comment: @Patrick I added something to my answer to try, `composer create-project -n "zendframework/skeleton-application":"dev-master"` maybe specify explicitly what version you want, in this case im just using the latest master.

Comment: It looks like Composer refuses to install the Zend skeleton from dev-master on my version of PHP-CLI (which is 5.4.x), even if I explicitly ask for the "dev-master" version of the framework. (Composer explicitly throws an error saying that it couldn't find the package "in a version installable using your PHP version.") 

That limitation on my end certainly doesn't reflect on the quality of your answer, which I'll mark as the correct one. Thanks for all the time you put into this. I believe that this answer will save someone a lot of time in the future.

Comment: You know what that makes sense, the latest skeleton project requests php 5.6 or 7.0 so thats why its not working for you the same way. Sorry it took so long to get to that answer

Answer (score 1):

Two things I've noticed: when you first initialize a skeleton application, depending on your settings, development mode is enabled by default.

If you want to run

```
composer development-enable
```

or any other similar commands, you must be in your `path/to/install` or `path/to/yourapp` directory for it to work! This is the folder that contains your local composer install. If you are in any of the parent directories, the command will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this similar problem when trying to enable development mode with the command `composer development-enable` on my apigility app. I was getting error:

zf-development-mode is not recognised as an internal or external command.

There is a page on the apigility website regarding the development mode module:
https://apigility.org/documentation/modules/zf-development-mode

I found by following the instruction to install the module from composer:

```
$ composer require zfcampus/zf-development-mode
```

Then making a copy of the development config file:

```
$ cp vendor/zfcampus/zf-development-mode/development.config.php.dist config/
```

Now using the `composer development-enable` seems to work fine, which in my case returned the message 'Already in development mode'.